# How to substring a spannable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spannable

I know how to take substring a normal string.

But how can I substring a spannable.

Consider following example.

Th**is** is **my sample s**entence.

now when I substring this i want to get the string "**mple s**ente" just like this and with all this formatings.

In another words I want to substring a spannable not a string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Spannable` is a `CharSequence` and you should be able to use `CharSequence.subSequence(int start, int end)` without losing any information about the spannable

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can get substring from spannable:

```
SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(s);
        ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f), 0, 6, 0); // set size
        ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 6, 0);
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Click here to learn more");
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textview.setText(ss);
```

Hope it helps you.